# Excel How to add different columns and rows in single cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to create a formula (refer to screenshot) in single cell i.e. O1, where I have to make A1,B1 and C1 stationary and make changes in E,G,I,K and M columns. Now the thing is how I can contatinate all these data in one cell, so that I can create below formatted formula

```
aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress --group-id sg-0bd7ffbc0d41840f6 --ip-permissions IpProtocol=tcp,FromPort=3306,ToPort=3306,UserIdGroupPairs="[{GroupId=sg-0a7eaebc18bdad397,Description=Allow MySQL to communicate with Tomcat application}]" IpProtocol=tcp,FromPort=11211,ToPort=11211,UserIdGroupPairs="[{GroupId=sg-0a7eaebc18bdad397,Description=Allow Memcache to communicate with Tomcat application}]"
```

[image]

Comment: Does `=TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,$A$1:$C$1,E1,G1,I1,K1)` do what you want? Notice the $ around A1:C1 that will lock those rows and columns. The references in E:K will change as you copy the formula to different rows / columns.

Comment: you do realize that the value attributable to referencing any cell in the markdown text drastically diminishes when you do this in reference to a screenshot i.e. "refer to screenshot... i.e. O1" when all row and column headers have been cropped out of view, don't you?

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you =$A$1&$B$1&$C$1&E1&G1&I1&K1&M1
Or i have misunderstood the question

Comment: So this is what I want, keeping A1, B1 & C1 cells stationary i.e. **A1**:aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress --group-id ; **B1**:sg-0bfbd62af7667776e; **C1**:  --ip-permissions 
and I would like to add D1,D2,D3...+E1,E2,E3...+F1,F2,F3... till N1,N2,N3... columns in O1 cell something like
**Row1**: IpProtocol=ICMP,FromPort=-1,ToPort=-1,IpRanges="[{CidrIp=$IP/32,Description= Allow ICMP port from My IP}]" 
**Row2**: IpProtocol=tcp,FromPort=22,ToPort=22,UserIdGroupPairs="[{GroupId=sg-0bfbded,Description=Allow SSH port from SG}]"
So that my End result is **A1+B1+C1+Row1+Row2+Row3...RowN**

Comment: In more concise manner I want to achieve this
=CONCATENATE(A4,B4,C4,D4,E4,F4,G4,H4,I4,J4,K4,L4,M4,N4,D5,E5,F5,G5,H5,I5,J5,K5,L5,M5,N5,D6,E6,F6,G6,H6,I6,J6,K6,L6,M6,N6,D7,E7,F7,G7,H7,I7,J7,K7,L7,M7,N7,D8,E8,F8,G8,H8,I8,J8,K8,L8,M8,N8....Dn,En,Fn..Nn)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).